# FormData Append method doesn't work in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app where I want to implement upload of images to the server. I'm stuck on the moment where I must append chosen file to the newly created FormData. Here is my TypeScript component relevant part:

```
imageData: File = null;
avatar = null;

fileProgress(fileInput: any) {
  this.imageData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
  this.avatar = new FormData();
  this.avatar.append('avatar', this.imageData);
  console.log(this.avatar, this.imageData)
}
```

This is what appears in console - `FormData {} File {name: "background.jpg", lastModified: 1579183010623, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jan 16 2020 15:56:50 GMT+0200, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8272, …}`

So basically I don't understand why I can't append already existing `this.imageData` with value to `this.avatar`, when I try to append it, it's value doesn't change and i still have empty array = `FormData {}`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you log `this.avatar.get('avatar')`?

Comment: And it's not an Angular problem. Try doing this in your browser's dev tools. You will see similar behaviour

Comment: It logs `File {name: "c6a60a43d7.png", lastModified: 1578421705098, lastModifiedDate: Tue Jan 07 2020 20:28:25 GMT+0200 (Восточная Европа, стандартное время), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 257877, …}` for `this.avatar.get('avatar')`

Answer (score 1):

Appending a value to 'avatar' in FormData, adds a value to the 'avatar' key. If you'd like to retrieve the values in a given key, you'd execute `this.avatar.get('avatar')`

It seems as though the file is retrieved and stored successfully in your example, is there anything that isn't working in particular?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should investigate.

fileReader = new FileReader ();

fileReader.onload = function(evt) {

```
 ....
```

})

Comment: What exactly should I investigate?